# Id reservado em transação com violação de chave

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Em uma operação de **INSERT** em uma tabela quando ocorre uma violação de chave e é feito um **ROOLBACK** da transação, o **ID** continua reservado? Abaixo exemplos ilustartivos:

*Script da tabela de teste*

```
CREATE TABLE    tb_teste(
    id_teste        INT IDENTITY            CONSTRAINT pk_tb_teste_id_teste      PRIMARY KEY,
    ds_status       VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT uk_tb_teste_ds_status     UNIQUE,
    dt_inclusao     DATETIME    NOT NULL    CONSTRAINT df_tb_teste_dt_inclusao   DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

Script para o **INSERT**:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        INSERT INTO
            tb_teste
                (ds_status)
        VALUES
                ('teste')
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

*Mensagem de erro no segundo **INSERT** por tentar inserir o valor 'teste' duas vezes:*

```
Violação da restrição UNIQUE KEY 'uk_tb_teste_ds_status'. Não é possível inserir a chave duplicada no objeto 'dbo.tb_teste'. O valor de chave duplicada é (teste).
```

[image: Imagem da tabela após as execuções das instruções]

Minhas perguntas são:

1. Isto é um comportamento padrão do SQL SERVER?

2. Existe alguma maneira de evitar que uma instrução falha ocupe um id na tabela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailson, esse é um dos vários problemas quando se utiliza IDENTITY ou SEQUENCE.

Determinadas tabelas utilizam chave substituta como chave primária, no lugar de chave natural. Geralmente essa chave substituta é um valor numérico, sequencial e crescente. Em algumas aplicações não pode ocorrer salto na geração dessa sequência. Algo que parece simples torna-se complicado quando se considera a ocorrência de transações simultâneas nas mesmas tabelas e objetos. A solução é a criação de mecanismo próprio para gerar os valores sequenciis para chave.

No artigo **Geração de sequências numéricas** consta o método "Tabela de sequências", em que se utiliza tabela auxiliar para armazenar qual o último valor gerado da sequência. A implementação em procedimento armazenado da obtenção do próximo valor da sequência simplifica o processo. Na mesma tabela podem ser armazenados vários sequenciadores, para utilizações diferentes.

A utilização do procedimento armazenado pode ser para inserir uma única linha ou então para um bloco de linhas. Para uma única linha podemos ter algo como:

```
-- código #2.15
-- próximo valor disponível
declare @Prox_Valor int;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

EXECUTE dbo.GetSequence 
     @nome_seq= 'dbo.Pessoa.ID_Pessoa',
     @valor = @Prox_Valor output;

INSERT into dbo.Pessoa (ID_Pessoa, Nome_Pessoa)
  values (@Prox_Valor, 'Paulo Antunes');

COMMIT;

go
```

A transação é definida de forma explícita, sendo composta da chamada ao procedimento armazenado que obtém a próxima chave e do comando de inclusão da linha. Neste método a geração do próximo valor da sequência está dentro do mesmo bloco de transação do comando INSERT; isto é para garantir que não haja buracos na sequência gerada.

Os detalhes estão no artigo “[Geração de sequências numéricas](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/04/21/geracao-de-sequencias-numericas/)”, de minha autoria, do qual extraí trechos para esta resposta.

---

Criação da tabela auxiliar:

```
-- código #2.12 v2
USE banco; 
go

IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.tbSequence', 'U') is not null
  DROP TABLE dbo.tbSequence;

CREATE TABLE dbo.tbSequence (
     Seq varchar(30) not null unique,
     Valor int not null default 0
);
go
```

---

Criação do procedimento armazenado que gera a sequência:

```
-- código #2.13 v2
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.GetSequence') is not null
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.GetSequence;
go

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetSequence
     @nome_seq varchar(30), 
     @valor int output,
     @n int = 1
as
begin
set nocount on;
declare @retorno int, @NLinhas int;

set @valor= NULL;
UPDATE dbo.tbSequence
  set @valor = Valor = Valor + @n
  where Seq = @nome_seq;

SELECT @retorno= @@error, @NLinhas= @@rowcount;
IF @retorno = 0 
  begin
  IF @NLinhas = 1
    set @valor= @valor - @n +1
  else 
    set @retorno= -1; -- erro na geração do próximo valor
  end;

return @retorno;
end;
go
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado por sua resposta